# character_id= + id + correct= + correctOrIncorrect... how can I make this a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Ah, not used to strings in javascript.

```
character_id= + id + correct= + correctOrIncorrect
```

That is what I need to make into a string. If you cannot guess the variables in the string they are `id`, and `correctOrIncorrec`.

How can I make this into a javascript string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's a ajax call through jQuery

Then give jQuery a JS object of the parameters:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/something.url',
    data: {character_id: id, correct: correctOrIncorrect}
});
```

If you try to create a serialised `data` string of your own, you will have to worry about getting the URL-encoding right. So let jQuery work it out instead.

Comment: This looks like it. Will give it a try on the plane ride to CA

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
'character_id=' + id + 'correct=' + correctOrIncorrect
```

Comment: Parameters: {"character_id"=>"2correct=true"} that is what I'm getting

Comment: can you explain a little more

Comment: It's a ajax call through jQuery :)

Comment: so, it is basically json that you are getting. Correct me if i am wrong. so are you getting {"character_id"=>"2correct=true"} or {"character_id"=>"2","correct"="true"} because as per your question i guess you might be getting second value. please clarify.

Comment: it is json. not sure what secon is. but I'm just sending object

Comment: as per my understanding, you can try, var val = 'character_id=' + ajaxresponse.character_id + 'correct=' + ajaxresponse.correct